# Pixel resampling on GEE: best practices

Tags: gis, google-earth-engine

I got a bit concerned about the correct (or best practices) on resampling a raster from a pixel resolution (e.g.: 30 meters) to a coarse resolution (927 meters).
My question:

1. Is that fine to use only `reproject()`, indicating the projection of desired resolution? Or should I use `.reduceResolution()` and than, `.reproject()`?
   I [build a simples code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/a357e425828d5a07d5622d7f8d01a0a5) showing that both approaches return different results:

```
var treecover = gfc.select("treecover2000");
print(treecover);
var bioProj = bio.select('bio01').projection();
var treecoverNewProj = treecover.reproject(bioProj);
print(treecoverNewProj.projection().nominalScale());

var NewProjVal  = treecoverNewProj.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: treecoverNewProj.projection().nominalScale()});
print("with only reproject()", NewProjVal);

var treecoverRedRes = treecover.reduceResolution({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      maxPixels: 1112
    }).reproject(bioProj);

var NewProjVal2  = treecoverRedRes.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: treecoverRedRes.projection().nominalScale()});
print("w reduce resoluction", NewProjVal2);
```

2. When dealing with categorical raster, which reducer should I use, in case I have to use the `reduceResolution()`? Is there a nearest-neighbor reducer?

Thanks in advance
Felipe